# How do you do logic on Post request sent from react in django?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django

When making a website (django and react) with its own currency. How can one use the data from the post method from react to do some logic on it and then return back the user info?

Example:
User has 20 coins, tries to buy something for 15 coins

If user has more than 15 coins:
User coins = User coins - 15
Return user info

Else:
Return "user does not have sufficient funds"

Comment: I recommend that you learn about basic examples of frontend <-> backend systems. There are oversimplified blogs/videos/whatever that would give you an idea how this works. Something like how a shopping frontend displays the page, calls the backend, queries the database, returns the result to frontend, and so on.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.